# passport.js + express: TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I use pasport.js + Express.js and got error

```
TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
```

with this code

passport/local.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var models = require("../../models");

module.exports = new LocalStrategy(
    function(username,password,done){
        models.User.findOne(
            {
                where:{username:username}
            },function(err,user){
                if(err){return done(err);}
                if(!user){return done(null,false,{message:"no such user"});}
                if(!user.validPassword(password)){return done(null,false,{message:"invalid password"});}
                return done(null,user);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require("passport");
var models = require("../models");
var local = require("./passport/local");

module.exports = () => {
    passport.serializeUser((user,done) => {
        done(null,user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id,done) => {
        models.User.findOne({
            where:{id:id}
        }).then(user => {
            done(null,user);
        }).catch(err => {
            done(err,null);
        });
    });

    console.log(typeof(local));
    passport.use(local);
}
```

console.log(typeof(local)); return "object". but passport.use() need function?

How can i solve this?

Comment: This code works for me. And object is what it should be. Could you check that all other files export something? Since it is your Router that complains, I think the problem is somewhere else, not with Passport.

Comment: Thank you!!!!
I forgot "module.exports = router" in one of my router file.

Comment: Cool. I sent an answer with the same and you can mark it as solution in case somebody has the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error comes from a missing export in one of the files that declares your routes. Please double check these files.

Also I checked and the code above works as it is.